# Why is the bone Tip and Root separated from the body of the bone in blender 2.8.Kindly assist

Tags: rigging, interface

When I add a bone in blender 2.8 the bone body happens not to be connected to the Tip and Root of the bone. How can I solve this problem?Kindly assist. I have also included a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing while using windows 7, I tried it on windows 10, and the problem was solved.

Also tried on Linux(Ubuntu) it works fine. It might be a bug associated with windows seven on certain hardwares.